# Bind Dropdownlist from database in Umbraco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

Here is a screenshot of  admin form

[Umbraco Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qknx5.png)

I want the field country to be bind to the database and I want the dropdown to allow multiple selection.

Is it possible in Umbraco?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible with a 3rd party package called nuPickers. There is a component called SQL Dropdown Picker in the package that allows you to bind the results from a sql query to a dropdown list.

You can find the package here: https://our.umbraco.com/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers/